# r - Error message while using h2o.deeplearning

Tags: r, deep-learning, classification, h2o

> ERROR MESSAGE:
>
> Illegal argument(s) for DeepLearning model: dl_model_faster.
> Details: ERRR on field: _stopping_metric: Stopping metric cannot be misclassification for regression.

I am getting this error but actually I am using h2o.deeplearning for a classification problem, I don't want to run regression model. How can I specify that?

Comment: Please post a MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve But my guess is that you need to specify distribution as bernoulli

Comment: what did you pass to the `distribution` parameters for `h2o.deeplearning`? If you didn't set it, try passing `distribution = "bernoulli"` or  "distribution = multinomial" (if this is a multinomial classification problem)

Comment: No actually this is a binary classification problem, but thank you @Lauren and @Richard it working when I specified `distribution = bernoulli` or `distribution = multinomial`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error for h2o.deeplearning(). Converting the dependent variable to factor and then feeding the data to h2o.deeplearning() fixed it for me.

```
dataset$dependent_variable= factor(dataset$dependent_variable,levels = c(0, 1), labels = c(0, 1))
```